# odeint simple 1d ode example does not compile

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I try to run [odeint examples](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/examples.html) in boost_1_54_0 on Debian Squeeze g++4.4

**Lorenz system** works fine, but **Simple 1d ode**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;


/* we solve the simple ODE x' = 3/(2t^2) + x/(2t)
 * with initial condition x(1) = 0.
 * Analytic solution is x(t) = sqrt(t) - 1/t
 */

void rhs( const double x , double &dxdt , const double t )
{
    dxdt = 3.0/(2.0*t*t) + x/(2.0*t);
}

void write_cout( const double &x , const double t )
{
    cout << t << '\t' << x << endl;
}

// state_type = double
typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< double > stepper_type;

int main()
{
    double x = 0.0; 
    //with the following line commented the program compiles
    integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type() ) ,
                        rhs , x , 1.0 , 10.0 , 0.1 , write_cout );
}
```

doesn't compile. There are 192 lines of errors that end with:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/range_algebra.hpp:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(double&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/range_algebra.hpp:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘end(double&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/range_algebra.hpp:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(const double&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/range_algebra.hpp:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(const double&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/range_algebra.hpp:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(double&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/range_algebra.hpp:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(double&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/range_algebra.hpp:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(double&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/range_algebra.hpp:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(double&)’
```

What's the problem?

Comment: It seems that you are using g++ 4.4, which does not support the feature `std::begin`, which appears since C++11. You may try to update your gcc compiler to a recent version.(not sure about this, so it is a comment not an answer)

Comment: @taocp, I tried to compile this with C++11 features enabled: `g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp  -o test` but the error is the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example on the webpage is only running with the github version of odeint. If you change the stepper type to

```
typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< double , double , double , double , vector_space_algebra > stepper_type;
```

it should run. We have included a automatic algebra detection mechanism which is not in the official boost version but which will be included very soon.

Comment: Thanks! I struggled for a couple of hours trying to replace gsl solver with boost::numeric::odeinit solver. Will this feature be back-ported to older boost-versions?

Comment: No, we will not back-port this feature. I think is also not the boost way. There are now backports in boost. At least I don't know of any backports.