# Template parameters of `boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta-X` compatible with CUDA/OpenMP

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, odeint

The type signature for class stepper I am using is summarized here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost/numeric/odeint/runge_kutta_dopri5.html

It can be instantiated as follows:

```
 boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type_ > stepper;
```

So far so good. It works.

I plan to port my program to cuda (using thrust) and later to openmp. I changed the declaration to following:

```
boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type_
        , double
        , state_type_
        , double
        , boost::numeric::odeint::vector_space_algebra 
        > stepper;
```

I followed solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808931/odeint-simple-1d-ode-example-does-not-compile/18809739#18809739) but this does not compile.

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/euler.hpp:26:
/usr/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/default_operations.hpp:87:27: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >')
            t1 = m_alpha1 * t2 + m_alpha2 * t3;
                 ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~
```

I am wondering what is the most portable way to declare the stepper so that minimum changes are required later when porting to cuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you want to do. If you want to use Thrust you need to change the declaration to

```
boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5<
    state_type , double , state_type , double ,
    thrust_algebra , thrust_operations >;
```

The `thrust_algebra` and the `thrust_operations` ensure that all computations are redirected to appropriate `thrust::for_each` calls where zipped iterators are used. If you want to use some high-level linear algebra library which runs on the GPU (like VexCL or ViennaCL) you can use your above declaration and only change the `state_type` to the correct type, for example `vexcl::vector< double >`. The `vector_space_algebra` assumes that your `state_type` can handle operations like `y = a1*x1 + a2*x2`, which is the case for VexCL and ViennaCL due to the use of expression templates. You can also have a look [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6326).

Comment: I see. This is nice. Also I have added compilation error message which I got with clang++. I am clueless about this warning; I am using the template  typenames as they are in example code. With first declaration where I pass only one template typename, it works fine (in fact performs slightly better than existing GSL integrator).

Comment: Your state_type is `vector< double >`. Vector space algebra means that you can write expressions like `a*x+b*y` which is not possible with `vector< double >`. Use a linear algebra library like Eigen!